# Removing window border in SWT UI disables re-positioning

Tags: java, user-interface, window, swt, borderless

Is there a way to remove SWT `Shell` border and also support window re-positioning. I used `SWT.NONE` in my Shell style to remove the window border but it also ended up in locking the UI position.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can, but you have to handle drag events yourself. Here is an example:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    final Display display = new Display();
    final Shell shell = new Shell(display, SWT.NO_TRIM | SWT.ON_TOP);

    Listener l = new Listener()
    {
        Point origin;

        public void handleEvent(Event e)
        {
            switch (e.type)
            {
                case SWT.MouseDown:
                    origin = new Point(e.x, e.y);
                    break;
                case SWT.MouseUp:
                    origin = null;
                    break;
                case SWT.MouseMove:
                    if (origin != null)
                    {
                        Point p = display.map(shell, null, e.x, e.y);
                        shell.setLocation(p.x - origin.x, p.y - origin.y);
                    }
                    break;
            }
        }
    };
    shell.addListener(SWT.MouseDown, l);
    shell.addListener(SWT.MouseUp, l);
    shell.addListener(SWT.MouseMove, l);

    shell.setSize(400, 300);
    shell.open();

    while (!shell.isDisposed())
    {
        if (!display.readAndDispatch())
        {
            display.sleep();
        }
    }
    display.dispose();
}
```

It's not really worth posting a screenshot, since it's just a draggable grey window.

**Update**

If you want the whole `Shell` to be draggable even if it contains other widgets, then use this instead:

```
    display.addFilter(SWT.MouseDown, l);
    display.addFilter(SWT.MouseUp, l);
    display.addFilter(SWT.MouseMove, l);
```

Comment: Just curious, with this I am able to drag my UI only from the top part of the shell and not all parts, maybe SWT makes your window behave that way by default

Comment: @Abbas As it is, the code will only drag the window if you drag unoccupied space on the `Shell`, i.e. space where there are no widgets. Do you want it to be draggable in any case? Then the widgets wouldn't be able to receive mouse events.

Comment: Ok Now I get it. No, I want the widgets in my composites to receive their mouse events. The area where I could drag the shell had a composite though with a canvas in it as a child displaying a Close Symbol.The canvas is the only widget in that composite.

Comment: @Abbas So is your question still valid? If so, can you explain it again?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/50864/discussion-between-abbas-and-baz)